# Syntactic understanding needed in Objective -C language

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, syntax

I have been coding application from past 1 year, However first time I came across a weird looking selector argument,

```
- (NSString *)dictionaryForString:(NSDictionary *)dictionary error:(NSError **)error
```

As you can see `(NSDictionary *)` is with one asterisks and `(NSError **)` with two, So what is the difference between having one or two asterisks?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This method returns an error *by reference*, that is, you pass it an address of a pointer to an NSError and it (optionally) sets the pointer value.

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *result = [obj dictionaryForString: dict error: &error];
if (!result)
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
```

This is a common C practice.

Answer (score 2):

NSDictionary* means it's the starting address of a NSDictionary object in memory
NSError** means it's pointed to the starting memory address to a NSError object